# RabbitMQ publish and consume same queue in simultaneously

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I have a RabbitMQ message queue and I want to publish multiple messages to the queue from a web service call **ServiceA**. Meantime, there is an another web service called **ServiceB** which is implemented for consuming the messages from the RabbitMQ same queue in an interval of 10 seconds time period. Is this use case possible with the implementation of the RabbitMQ queues?

Does RabbitMQ support to access the **same queue** by the publisher and consumer at the same time (simultaneously)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ServiceB which is implemented for consuming the messages from the RabbitMQ same queue in an interval of 10 seconds time period.

It's a little bit strange to implement this by RabbitMQ. In RabbitMQ, consumer channel will receive message immediately unless its unAck messages reach [the prefetch limit](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html). I recommend to add a **Buffer Cache (flush every 10 seconds)** between RabbitMQ consumer and **ServiceB**.

> Does RabbitMQ support to access the same queue by the publisher and consumer at the same time (simultaneously)?

In RabbitMQ, publisher can't access queue directly, you can only publish message to  exchange, RabbitMQ Daemon will route message by the exchange binding rule. In other words, publisher and consumer can work independently and simultaneously.

Comment: This is the phase I'm looking for - "publisher and consumer can work independently and simultaneously.". Thanks for your clarification.